# Mysql advanced query

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'postac' for update in FROM clause
```

on query:

```
UPDATE postac
SET statek= (
    SELECT statek
    FROM postac
    WHERE nazwa='Bjorn')
WHERE nazwa='*a*';
```

Can someone fix this ?

Comment: Have you look at the related questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: This behaviour is explained in the [documentation of the `UPDATE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html): *"You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."*

Comment: What if the subquery returns more than one row? The logic of the query is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
update postac p1
inner join postac p2 on p1.id = p2.id and p2.nazwa='Bjorn'
set p1.statek = p2.statek
where p1.nazwa='*a*'
```

Comment: Assuming `id` is the `PK` of the table, your query is a `no-op`.